# 404 error when viewing the details, Polls Django

Tags: python, django

I went the tutorial for building the Django Polls website, but i got an error when I clicked the questions to see the details. The error message:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^polls/ ^$ [name='index']
    ^polls/ ^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
    ^polls/ ^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$ [name='results']
    ^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
    ^admin/
    The current URL, polls/“/polls/7/”, didn't match any of these.
```

I am not sure why it returns me the URL polls/“/polls/7/”. here is how i wrote the template:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
     <ol>
     {% for q in latest_question_list %}
         <li><a href=“{% url "polls:detail" q.id %}”>{{ q.question_text }}</a></li>
     {% endfor %}
     </ol>
{% else %}
     <p> No Polls are available. </p>
{% endif %}
```

Follow-up on this question:
I finally solved this issue by changing the smart link to the hard coded link.

Comment: did you try it as `{% url "detail" q.id %}` ?

Comment: I tried, but i did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using curly ("smart") quotes in your code. They're not recognised by Django or your browser.

Swap them for normal quotes, and make sure you're using a text editor, not a word processor, to write your code.

Comment: i think you are right, my python is still 2.7, but Django is 1.9. the manual said it was written for python 3.4 and Django 1.9

Comment: Django 1.9 would require python version greater than 3.

Comment: you are right, i changed smart coding to hard coding, which works. i think i will use python 3 for this.